# What is the probability of no collision in two hash tables, where a key is hashed to both tables and chained to the shortest chain from the tables?

Tags: hash-tables

can someone help me with this problem? Consider a hashing scheme that uses r hash tables T1, . . . , Tr of size m, where collisions in each table are resolved by chaining. When a key k arrives, it is hashed into each table Ti using hash function hi, and then stored in table Ti having the smallest chain in location hi(k). Suppose that we hash n keys and use m = O(n^1.5) and r = 2. Show that with probability at least 1/2, there will be no collisions in any of the (two) tables.

I found that the probability of no collision in a single table is m!/((m^n)*(m-n)!) but how do we extend this to two tables?

Comment: Please credit the original source where you encountered this task.  See https://cs.stackexchange.com/help/referencing